# Print view form like from browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, odoo, openerp-7

I need to create button that would open print option (and option to save in pdf format) for the current view form. 
Now it is possible to do so by going into print options in browser (like in chrome). But can I do it to open such print option directly by pressing button in openerp form?

Something like:

```
<button name="Print"/>
```

and it would open same thing that is opened when you go to browser options and choose print.

I found something similar in point of sale module when you press Validate button it opens that menu for check to pay. But haven't figured out how it is done. Do I need to use javascript /jQuery for that or something?

For example to open something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="window.print();">
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but if I make this way, it creates button with different look than the rest of buttons in openerp, even if I use class="oe_highlight". Is it possible to get same style for input as it is in openerp `button` tag or maybe I can somehow use it with `button` tag so button style would be kept the same?

Comment: Try this way and see if it looks like the other buttons    <button name="Print" onclick="window.print();">

Comment: I tried that, it looks the same, but then it stops working as `button` tag requires another elements. Also even if I do something like this `<button name="dummy_print", string="Print", onclick="window.print()" type="object"/>` and create dummy method, so it would only return True, then I don't get any errors, but pressing button, nothing happens. It seems button, ignores `onclick` element, or maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: Well there is no OpenERP framework for fiddling it.. The thing is that `button` tag is used in xml, not html, so it might behave differently than in normal html.